# Git workflow for one-man web development version control

Tags: php, wordpress, git, svn, themes

I am using a commercial theme for one of my (wordpress) websites, but I always have difficulties merging my custom theme (especially parent theme changes) changes with the newer theme versions, developed by the theme author. This happens because there are always things I need to change in the parent theme.

I was wondering what system (git/svn or something else...) could help me merging my customizations with the future updates. So far I am using .txt files to save my customizations, but this is not a good way to do this.

I have tried git, but I am not sure how to use it in the right way since many files will be overwritten by the next theme update.

Could anyone help me figuring out a git workflow to solve this problem?

Thx,

Engin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With git you will have 2 branches:

1. **Master branche** - your customizations and production code
2. **Theme branche** - branch with original theme files

**Start:**
Create **master branche** with theme without customizations. Clone this branch to **theme branche**.

**How to develop:**
So you will be develop at **master branche**. If some new updates will be released for your theme you switch to **theme branche**, here you will delete full theme folder and add new theme folder (need delete because of deleted files in new theme release). Then commit to server and now merge **theme branche** to **master branche**. After that you resolve only conflicts between your code and new theme code.